Algebraic variety and its relation to SU(3) group structure
I'm investigating an algebraic variety defined by the following system of equations:
$$
\begin{align}
a^2 + b^2 + f_{01}^2 + f_{02}^2 + f_{03}^2 + f_{12}^2 + f_{13}^2 + f_{23}^2 &= 1 \\
-2af_{01} + 2f_{02}f_{12} - 2f_{03}f_{13} - 2bf_{23} &= 0 \\
-2af_{02} - 2f_{01}f_{12} - 2bf_{13} + 2f_{03}f_{23} &= 0 \\
-2af_{03} - 2bf_{12} + 2f_{01}f_{13} - 2f_{02}f_{23} &= 0
\end{align}
$$
where $a$, $b$, and $f_{ij}$ are real variables.
The first equation resembles a normalization condition for SU(4), but the others further restrict it. Because of this restriction, clearly it cannot contain the SU(4) group. But perhaps it can contain the SU(3) group as the largest group that can fit into this variety?

Does this algebraic variety contain a subspace that is isomorphic to the Lie group SU(3)?

If not, what is the relationship, if any, between this variety and SU(3)?


I'm particularly interested in understanding the geometric and group-theoretic properties of this variety and its potential connections to Lie group structures in physics. Any insights or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.

Where did these equations show up? Usually a more conceptual definition is easier to work with than a raw system of equations. Are these dot products or entries of a matrix product, for example ?

@QiaochuYuan its from this equation $(a-f+b)\gamma_0(a+f+b)=\gamma_0$, where a is a scalar, f a bivector and b a pseudo-scalar of GA(3,1). for the equation to satisfied, all 4 equations above must hold.

So this is a computation in geometric algebra. Can you write it down in more detail? It sounds like you're computing the set of rotors stabilizing $\gamma_0$ or something like that but I'm not sure what $\gamma_0$ refers to.

(This is important context because this thing might be automatically a Lie group but I'm not sure if the rotor you've written down is general enough. If it is that narrows things down significantly and is important information!)

@QiaochuYuan $\gamma_0$ is one of the Dirac gamma matrices that generates the GA(3,1) with $\gamma_0,\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3$.

Can you write it down in terms of the generators of the geometric algebra? You have to understand that this notation is all physics notation, mathematicians are not generally familiar with it.

@QiaochuYuan $a+f+b$ means $a+f_{01}e_0e_1+f_{02}e_0e_2+f_{03}e_0e_3+f_{12}e_1e_2+f_{13}e_3e_1+f_{23}e_2e_3+be_0e_1e_2e_3$. and the stabilizing condition is $(a-f+b)e_0(a+f+b)=e_0$. The product $(a-f+b)e_0(a+f+b)$ gives: $(a^2 + b^2 + f_{01}^2 + f_{02}^2 + f_{03}^2 + f_{12}^2 + f_{13}^2 + f_{23}^2)e_0 + (-2af_{01} + 2f_{02}f_{12} - 2f_{03}f_{13} - 2bf_{23})e_1 + (-2af_{02} - 2f_{01}f_{12} - 2bf_{13} + 2f_{03}f_{23})e_2 + (-2af_{03} - 2bf_{12} + 2f_{01}f_{13} - 2f_{02}f_{23})e_3$
